# Концентрические цветные кольца в Leaflet. Как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Задача: нарисовать в leaflet концентрические кольца, примыкающие друг к другу. При наведении (mouseover) на кольцо будет висеть свой обработчик, который в числе прочего, меняет прозрачность (с 0.8 на 0.5). Именно поэтому использовать circle(), вставленные в друг друга невозможно - при изменении прозрачности внешнего меняется прозрачность всех (а круги разного цвета плюс ко всему).
Знаю, что это можно реализовать. Как это сделать? Как задать кольцо с r1 и r2 (внешний/внутренний радиус), что бы оно было полигоном?

Answer (score 0):

По идее, алгоритм может быть таким:

1. создать объект `L.FeatureGroup()`, который будет содержать в себе два объекта `L.Circle`, отвечающие за внешний и внутренний радиусы (п.1 не обязателен, но больше для удобства - в каждом таком объекте по два `L.Circle`, чтобы проще было использовать);
2. Затем каждый `L.Circle` надо преобразовать в `L.Polygon` (как множество точек заданной окружности) - тут математика в помощь, как получить множество точек зная радиус и центр окружности;
3. После этого преобразования получаем массив координат большего круга (через `getLatLngs()`) и добавляем к нему массив координат меньшего круга;
4. из нового массива с координатами создаем новый `L.Polygon` который как раз и будет выглядеть как "пончик";